# Can I use the openById function with a variable that includes a range on the active spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm hoping to get some help as I've been stuck on this code for a few days now. I'm trying to create a report that distributes information to a various number of sub reports with a click of a button. My initial thought was to add in the spreadsheet ID to the corresponding row of information needed to distribute. For instance, Column M contains the various report IDs and Columns A --> L has the information to distribute.

The row range to distribute information is based off of a variable loop to check for nonblank rows starting in row 4. The issue I'm running into is that the range is not getting picked up when inputting the variable range into openById.

Here's the error:

> Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp. (line 8, file "Code")

Current code:

```
function mSOW() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
  var lastrow = ss.getLastRow()
  for(var RequestItem = 4; RequestItem < lastrow; RequestItem++);
  
    if(ss.getRange(RequestItem,1).getValue() !== "") {
      var Subreportkey = ss.getRange(RequestItem,13).getValue(); //Spreadsheet ID range
      var Subreport = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Subreportkey); //
      var Subreportsheet = Subreport.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
      var Subreportlastrow = Subreportsheet.getLastRow();
      var Subreportrange = Subreportsheet.getRange(Subreportlastrow,1,1,8);
      
      var mSOWrequestdatarange = ss.getRange('A' + RequestItem + ':L' + RequestItem)
      var mSOWrequestdata = mSOWrequestdatarange.getValues()

      }
     }
```

Comment: What is the value of `Subreportkey` ?

Comment: Looks like a server error. Try in a new sheet  and project.

Comment: @Marios That would throw a **permission** error. This isn't related to that.

Comment: Hi Marios & TheMaster, thanks for getting back so fast. The subreportkey contains the report id which I've put in various formats with single/double quotes. I still run into the same error when producing this into a new sheet/project.

Comment: @Marios The current value isn't a custom function and I am just using the report ID from the url. Later, I will be using the vlookup function to get the report ID.

Comment: @TheMaster, any other diagnosis I could be looking at to fix the problem? I received the same error when creating a new project/script.

Comment: @RichardLiu Create a  New empty spreadsheet and cooy paste the script and run the script ( after changing sheet name and adding some dummy data). Is that what you've done ?

Comment: @TheMaster, Yup, put it in a new spreadsheet and ran the script. It still popped up the same error. When importing the range, it could find the spreadsheet and I gave access.

Comment: Looking [for similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getting+the+method+or+property+openById+on+object+SpreadsheetApp),  it would seem the problem is probably in `Subreportkey`(Sheet1!A4's value). It needs to be a plain spreadsheet id without any quotes.

Comment: @TheMaster, it seems to have been the formatting which changed everything. I was able to pick up the idkey through changing the format too plain text rather than using the auto formatting. Thank you!

Comment: @RichardLiu Great. Added a answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Subreportkey = ss.getRange(RequestItem,13).getValue(); //Spreadsheet ID range
var Subreport = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Subreportkey); //ID from.sheet1!A4
```

Reading into [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getting+the+method+or+property+openById+on+object+SpreadsheetApp), the problem usually occurs if Supersetm spreadsheet id (`SubreportKey`) is somehow invalid.

OP confirmed that the format of the cell was a issue. Changing the format to plain cell resolved the issue.